# Jquery accordion not collapsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So im busy creating a Newsletter archive by using a Jquery accordion for my client. Each month in essence is an accordion (So the month itself is expandable and collapsible) and every article too. My first month (January) is working perfectly but for some reason, none of the others work as expected. The other "months" can expand and collapse but not their articles. I have tried amending the Javascript countless times but to no avail.

Here is the link to the test site:
http://promisedev.co.za/eam/gt/

If anybody has any suggestions or advice it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you show us your code?

Comment: Have you tried using the `toggle` option in the plugin? Pass `.akordeon({toggle: false});` upon initialisation.

Comment: For some reason, on the first block (Jan) when you expand an article, it's content element height is being changed (from 0 to a visible value). On the other blocks (Feb, Mar, etc), it's not happening. It stays at 0, hence invisible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the problem is with your `jquery.akordeon.js` file. you can delete this file and use this JQuery code. I edited your code you can use this:

[**jsFiddle is here**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/5BPZ4/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//Hide the tooglebox when page load
$(".togglebox").hide();
$(".togglebox:first").show();
    $(".akordeon-item-head").next(".akordeon-item-body").hide();
//slide up and down when click over heading 2
$("h1").click(function(){
// slide toggle effect set to slow you can set it to fast too.
$(this).next(".togglebox").slideToggle("slow");
return true;
});
    /* here is the new Codes*/
    $(".akordeon-item-head").click(function(){

        $(this).next(".akordeon-item-body").slideToggle();

    });   
});
```

Comment: Hi Mohsen, I have just implemented your code and everything is now working as expected so thanks very much! (To everyone else thanks much too). Now my next question is what would the simplest way be to get the plus and minus icons working as before but using your Jquery?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is remove inline styles such as `height: 154px` and `height: 0` and set height in a local/external css:

```
<style>
    .akordeon-item-body { height: 154px; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to use an accordeon mechanism on some site and finally ended up coding it on my own

Fiddle test case <[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/stphane/rQZ7b/)>

The important part is to store last slided element

```
$("#commonAncestor").on('click', function (e) {
    var $me = $(this),
        $clicked = $(e.target).closest('.clickableArea', this),
        $lastClicked = $me.data('active') || $([]),
        ...
});
```